# Notification in ViewController when ViewModel completes operation

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

I'm making a simple iOS app in order to learn ReactiveCocoa. I've been using XIB files till this moment, but decided to switch to the storyboard.
In my first view I have login screen, and when user presses button, viewModel executes RACCommand to authenticate user and download his contacts list. After that I need to call `performSegueWithIdentifier:` from ViewController to display downloaded data. How is it possible to be notified in ViewController, that viewModel successfully completed its operations?

Here is code snippet from ViewController:

```
RAC(self.viewModel, username) = self.usernameTextField.rac_textSignal;
RAC(self.viewModel, password) = self.passwordTextField.rac_textSignal;
self.loginButton.rac_command = self.viewModel.executeSignin;
```

And snippet from its ViewModel:

```
////////////////////////////////IN INIT////////////////////////////////////
self.executeSignin =
    [[RACCommand alloc] initWithEnabled:validAuthenticateSignal
                            signalBlock:^RACSignal *(id input) {
                                return  [self executeSigninSignal];
                            }];
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

-(RACSignal *)executpsigninsignal {
    return [[[self.services getAuthenticationService]
             authenticationSignalFor:self.username andPassword:self.password]
            //Return user if exists
            flattenMap:^RACStream *(STUser *user) {
                return [[[[[self services] getContactsLoadService]
                 contactsLoadSignalForUser:user] deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]]
                //Return user contacts
               doNext:^(NSArray *contacts) {
                   _downloadedContacts = [NSArray arrayWithArray:contacts];
               }];

            }];
}
```

I also tried to observe ViewModels downloadedContacts property in ViewController:

```
RACSignal *contactsLoadSignal = RACObserve(self.viewModel, downloadedContacts);
[[contactsLoadSignal filter:^BOOL(NSArray *value) {
    return value!=nil && value.count>0;
}]subscribeNext:^(NSArray *array) {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushContactsList" sender:self];
}];
```

But this doesn't seem to work and does't really look nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command's `executionSignals` property to do that:

```
@weakify(self)
[executeSignin.executionSignals.switchToLatest filter:^BOOL(NSArray *value) {
    return value.count>0;  //nil check was redundant here
}] subscribeNext:^(NSArray *array) {
    @strongify(self)
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"pushContactsList" sender:self];
}];
```